# Autofill Form when click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I read a lot of entries here on StackOverflow about what I need and I also implemented a method that I found here. Well it is not working as it should and I hope someone can tell me why.

I have a form with 7 input fields. What I need is a button and if someone clicks on the button, the form will be autofilled, always with the same text on every field. I should work something like this:

Form: 
Input 1: empty,
Input 2: empty,
Input 3: empty,
Input 4: empty,
Input 5: empty,
Input 6: empty,
Input 7: empty,

So the seven input fields are empty. Now if someone clicks on the button, the input fields should all get the same value and it should look like this:

Input 1: AUTOFILLED,
Input 2: AUTOFILLED,
Input 3: AUTOFILLED,
Input 4: AUTOFILLED,
Input 5: AUTOFILLED,
Input 6: AUTOFILLED,
Input 7: AUTOFILLED

Let me show you what I did. I created the following button:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" onClick="autoFill('Suppenbuffet'); return false;" role="button">Suppenbuffet</a>
```

Then I wrote the following JS code:

```
<script>
        function autoFill(vorspeise) {
            document.getElementById('vorspeise').value = vorspeise;           
        }
    </script>
```

And then I entered the id="vorspeise" to all my input fields like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input 1:  </label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
   <input type="text" name="vorspeise-traditionell-montag" id="vorspeise" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $yy ?>" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input 2:  </label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
   <input type="text" name="vorspeise-traditionell-dienstag" id="vorspeise" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $yy ?>" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input 3:  </label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
   <input type="text" name="vorspeise-traditionell-mittwoch" id="vorspeise" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $yy ?>" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem now is, that if I click the button, ONLY the first input field will be autofilled and not all seven input fields. Can someone tell me how I need to change the code so that this will affect all input fields with the id="vorspeise" ?!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: yeah because you are giving the same Id to all the input fields, Ids must be unique for every element!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID must be unique otherwise it will returned first matched element only. Change the id into class definition like so :

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input 1:  </label>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <input type="text" name="vorspeise-traditionell-montag" class="form-control vorspeise" value="<?php echo $yy ?>" required>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input 2:  </label>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
 <input type="text" name="vorspeise-traditionell-dienstag" class="form-control vorspeise" value="<?php echo $yy ?>" required>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Input 3:  </label>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
 <input type="text" name="vorspeise-traditionell-mittwoch" class="form-control vorspeise" value="<?php echo $yy ?>" required>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function autoFill(vorspeise) {
   $('.vorspeise').val(vorspeise);          
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/gzkn1rxz/)**

Comment: That´s it! Thank you @Norlihazmey Ghazali! Just one more question, what does my JS function have to look like, if I want to do exactly the same with checking a checkbox? So instwead an autofill to text fields, it should be an autocheck to checkboxes

Comment: JS depend on your HTML structure, you can use `.prop()` to check those checkbox

Comment: Can you add a demo for checkboxe to your JSfiddle? I would really appreciate that

Comment: Check **DEMO** link again. See the example.

Comment: Thanks for the demo! Really appreciate your help and will select your answer as the "right" one.

Answer (score 0):

IDs:are unique (or supposed to be) so you need to adress them by a class, or by unique id:s

Example:

```
function autoFill(vorspeise) {
            document.getElementById('vorspeise1').value = vorspeise;           
            document.getElementById('vorspeise2').value = vorspeise;           
            document.getElementById('vorspeise3').value = vorspeise;           
        }
```

Or you can addres them by name:

```
document.getElementsByName("vorspeise-traditionell-mittwoch")[0].value = "bla"
document.getElementsByName("vorspeise-traditionell-dienstag")[0].value = "bla"
document.getElementsByName("vorspeise-traditionell-montag")[0].value = "bla"
```

Comment: Oh okay but I already need my class inside the input button so I guess I cannot create a second class and I need to create unique IDs, am I right?

Comment: you can adress them by class or by name or by id =) You can have multiple classes like this class="form-control vorspiese-class"

Comment: if I use 2 onClick buttons for two different fields they are interrupting each other even if they get two different IDs. Any idea how I can solve that? I want one button to fill out one input field and another button to fill out the other input field.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good idea to use multiple fields with same id. It will create problems is CSS, Scripting, etc.

Either use same class for all the input.

Or other way could be to use different ID's for each inputs.

I hope it helps :)